# ANGULAR - Template Method not executing onLoad

Tags: javascript, angular

Im doing a simple app, but for some reason, the parent methods, that Im invokes in the template, are not working.

1. Am I missing something?
2. Seams like the template is executed before the TS is ready. Is this possible? If yes, how to prevent it?

Template:

```
    <app-search-list
      [dataResults]="Pokemons"
      [pokemonArray]="pokemonDataArray"
      (dataPokemonEvent)="receivePokemonData($event)"
    ></app-search-list>

    <app-search (dataEvent)="receiveCustomData($event)">
      <p style="background-color: yellow">share data: {{ msg }}</p>
    </app-search>
```

typescript

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { SearchListComponent } from './search-list/search-list.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild(SearchListComponent) dataSearchList: any;
  @ViewChild(SearchComponent) dataSearch: any;
  @Input() msg: string = '{msg} not implemented';


  @Input() pokemonDataArray: Object[] = [];

  Pokemons = [  ];

  constructor() {}

  receiveCustomData(event: any) {
    this.msg = event;
    alert('receiveCustomData');
    console.log('receiveCustomData');
  }

  receivePokemonData(event: any) {
    console.log('receivePokemonData');
    alert('receivePokemonData');
    this.pokemonDataArray = event;
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    // this.receiveCustomData('Test');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into `SearchListComponent` and `SearchComponent`. Check out what triggers `dataPokemonEvent` and `dataEvent`.

Why are you declaring `ViewChild`s - you are not using it in `AppComponent`.

If you can chare also code of `SearchListComponent` and `SearchComponent`.

Answer (score -1):

I see a couple of things you can try. Be more specific with the type of @ViewChild, and at the @Input(), you're trying to interpolate but, since the variable `msg` hasn't been declared. I'm guessing you declared it in the parent, so try to fix that, either by removing msg, or passing the string that you need, and not defining it in the child.

```
@ViewChild(SearchListComponent) dataSearchList: SearchListComponent;
@ViewChild(SearchComponent) dataSearch: SearchComponent;
//@Input() msg: string = '{msg} not implemented';
```

Comment: And as a tip, I see that you define most of the variables as "any". Doing so, the app might work, but you're losing the advantage of using typescript, so I would highly advise you to not use it, since that "any" type should be used as a last resort.

Comment: The template that I added to the question, already is the parent. 
About the declaration, you right, I agree; the `any` is just for test for while, but it will be replaced. 

About your solution, do u suggest something like this? 

```
@ViewChild(SearchListComponent) dataSearchList: SearchListComponent;
  @ViewChild(SearchComponent) dataSearch: SearchComponent;

  constructor() {
    this.dataSearchList = new SearchListComponent;
    this.dataSearch = new SearchComponent;
  }
```

Comment: I just re-read your question, and it isn't quite clear what you want to pass down to the children views. With the events, you're passing just a reference to them, but never execute them, since the event 'dataEvent' isn't defined, therefore never executed.